# Breeze expanded properties - how to reference in controller arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze, hottowel

I am missing a key piece of understanding in my first attempt to pull full entity graphs for an entity with Breeze and EF6 (Hottowel/John Papa flavor)

I have a parent-child-grandchild relationship of **Policies-P_Locations-P_Hazards**

I want to see the graphs for all policies for one client

In short my query returns the JSON shaped at I expect (confirmed in XHR viewer) and the data.results allow me to drill down (through backingstore - man do we need a viewer on the javascript like C#) to see arrays for children and grandchildren.  I see all the policies, locations and hazards I expect for the client (dll version and model/modelmap code at the end of post)

**datacontext:**

```
    function getPoliciesByClientsId(clientsid) {

        var policies;

        return EntityQuery.from('Policies')
            .withParameters({ clientsid: clientsid })
            .expand('P_Locations, P_Locations.P_Hazards')
            .using(manager).execute()
            .then(querySucceeded, _queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            policies = data.results;
            log('Retrieved [Policy] from remote data source', policies.length, true);

            return policies;
        }

    }
```

**controller :**

```
function getPoliciesByClientsId(clientsid) {

    return datacontext.getPoliciesByClientsId(clientsid).then(function(data) {
        vm.Policies = [];
        vm.Policies = data;
// at this point vm.Policies shows an object array 
// and I can see p_Locations for each policy and p_Hazards for each location
// but vm.Policies.p_locations is undefined

            return vm.Policies;
        }
    );


}
```

If I drill into policies in datacontext or vm.Policies in controller I see the camel cased arrays.

**BUT**

**vm.Policies.p_Locations is undefined.**  And of course I want to reference vm.Policies.p_Locations.p_Hazards as well.

**What am I missing in order to reference the graph of data for binding**?

**BreezeController:**

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Policy> Policies()
{
    return _repository.Policies;
}
```

**PwiRepository**

```
    public IQueryable<Policy> Policies
    {
        get { return Context.Policies; }
    }
```

And that creates this **request** :

```
Request URL:http://localhost:29130/breeze/Breeze/Policies?$expand=P_Locations%2CP_Locations%2FP_Hazards&clients_id=439
```

Using **manager.metadataStore.getEntityType('P_Location')** and then drilling to **navigation properties** I find these

```
navigationProperties: Array[4]0: 

dassociationName: "P_Hazard_P_Location"
entityType: l
entityTypeName: "P_Hazard:#Pwi.Model.Models"
foreignKeyNames: Array[0]
foreignKeyNamesOnServer: Array[0]
invForeignKeyNames: Array[1]
invForeignKeyNamesOnServer: Array[1]
inverse: disScalar: falsename: "p_Hazards"
nameOnServer: "P_Hazards"
parentType: lvalidators: Array[0]

associationName: "P_Location_Policy"
entityType: lentityTypeName: "Policy:#Pwi.Model.Models"
foreignKeyNames: Array[1]
foreignKeyNamesOnServer: Array[1]
invForeignKeyNames: Array[0]
invForeignKeyNamesOnServer: Array[0]
inverse: disScalar: truename: "policy"
nameOnServer: "Policy"parentType: l
relatedDataProperties: Array[1]validators: Array[0]__proto__: Objectlength: 4
```

Here are the dll
 pieces

```
<packages>
  <package id="Breeze.Server.ContextProvider" version="1.4.17" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6" version="1.4.17" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.Server.WebApi2" version="1.4.17" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebActivator" version="1.5.3" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

I have a parent-child-grandchild relationship of Policies-P_Locations-P_Hazards 
Here are the relevant parts of the model and model mapping

P_Location Model :

```
public partial class P_Location
    {
        public P_Location()   
        {
            this.P_GlCoverages = new List<P_GlCoverage>();
            this.P_Hazards = new List<P_Hazard>();
            this.P_PropertyCoverages = new List<P_PropertyCoverage>();
        }
        public int P_Locations_id { get; set; }
        public int Policies_id { get; set; }
      ......

      public virtual Policy Policy { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<P_Hazard> P_Hazards { get; set; }
```

P_LocationMap

```
 // Relationships
            this.HasRequired(t => t.Policy)
                .WithMany(t => t.P_Locations)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.Policies_id);
```

P_Hazard Model

```
public Policy Policy { get; set; }
        public P_Location P_Location { get; set; }
```

P_HazardMap

```
  // Relationships
            this.HasRequired(t => t.P_Location)
                .WithMany(t => t.P_Hazards)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.P_Locations_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd check to make sure that the objects being returned by your query are in fact entities. i.e. do they each have an 'entityAspect' property?  If not, you are returning projections instead of entities.  This can happen for a variety of reasons but is usually due to either a namingConvention issue or the lack of a 'toType' call on your EntityQuery. (needed if the query endpoint is not in the entity type/resource name map which is often the case with parameterized queries).

I'd also look in the *MetadataStore* using *getEntityType* and making sure that the names of the properties for each of your entities is what you expect.

Can you also post the server side query?

Comment: Each entity into the grandchild seems to have an entityAspect property.  If I drill into p_Locations entityAspect.entityManager I see       metadataStore: i
_ctorRegistry: Object
_deferredTypes: Object
_entityTypeResourceMap: Object
...
P_Hazard:#Pwi.Model.Models: "P_Hazards"
P_Location:#Pwi.Model.Models: "P_Locations"
...
Policy:#Pwi.Model.Models: "Policies"
__proto__: Object  which are the models I expect.  Posting server side code above in orginal question.

Comment: I'm not sure I actually care but can anyone tell me who voted down this question and why?  I thought it explained the issue thoroughly and directly address Jay's request I post further information.

Comment: Ok, rereading your post, I'm not sure I understand when you say that "see all the policies, locations and hazard" but "Policies.p_Locations is undefined".  How can you have both? Where do you "see" the policies,locations and hazards?  Also, you should be accessing the "data.results" property in the "then" promise, not just "data".

Comment: Not sure who marked you down but I just scored it back up.

Comment: Thanks Jay.  I meant in the JSON I see all the expected data and in the data.results in datacontext I can drill Policies and see an array of p_Locations and then drill into each p_Location to see an array of p_Hazards.  I see these by drilling to the _backingstore in each case.  Same for drilling into vm.Policies which received the data in the controller.  My expectation was that vm.Policies.p_Locations would be a bindable array.  Do I need to explicitly declare vm.Policies.p_Locations = [] someplace?

Comment: Should add the "undefined" is the result in the watch window (Chrome) and in the Console in the appropriate scope.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a "bindable array". If you are using the "backingStore" model library you are presumably using Angular and Angular binds directly to any js object.

Comment: if "Policies" is an array then each "Policy" will have a "p_Locations" property, but the "Policies" array itself will not. i.e. "vm.Policies[0].p_Locations" will exist but "vs.Policies.p_Locations" will not exist, nor is it expected to.  Breeze is simply constructing a graph of the relations you request.